# Dynamic RouteTable doesn't work anymore since May 2022

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

I have an ASP.NET 4.8 project, Web Form, where I'm using the custom routing.
Everything worked perfectly until two months ago when it started not to work correctly.

In the Global.asax I register the routes:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    ...
}
```

The first line register the routes for the WebAPI I've integrated in the project:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "webapi/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

The second line, register the routes for the resources stored in the database and add also friendlyURLs:

```
foreach (var r in resources) //resource is coming from the DB...
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route(r.ResourceLink.Trim(), new PageRouteHandler("~/ResourceView.aspx")));
}

...

var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```

The routes are working perfectly when I run the application at the beginning.
The issue comes out when I add a new resource and I try to update at runtime the routing table. I see from debug that the new route item is added correctly but it's ignored when I made the request.

The code I use to add the resource at runtime is like the one I use to add resource routes from the DB:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route(r.ResourceLink.Trim(), new PageRouteHandler("~/ResourceView.aspx")));
```

The only difference I see in the RouteTable created at the application start and when I modified it at runtime is that the new route item is added after the routes for the friendlyURLs, but it has worked until a couple of months ago.

Any clue on how to solve this issue?

UPDATE

Inspecting the route table right after I've added a new route at runtime I see it correctly in the Routes collection, identical to the others, loaded from the DB:
[image]
If I try to access the resource at /data-management/data-storage/sample4 I get redirected to the wrong handler which is the last in the list before I added the new one at runtime, even if it doesn't match at all with the Url.

Comment: If you changed nothing, then probably something else changed. Like security features of modern browsers. Did you check things like CORS? You should get some errors of warnings in the output of your debugger, either browser or asp.net. if not, you should up the logging levels